# Arch Linux, Docker "No space left on device."

Tags: linux, docker, archlinux

All of the similar questions I see are resolved by cleaning up the images or containers or orphaned volumes but I am not having any of those problems.  I even completely deleted `/var/lib/docker` and still nothing.

Relevant output:

```
[N] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker martin/docker-cleanup-vol
umes
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/usr/local/bin/docker-cleanup-volumes.sh' not found or does not exist..
[N] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker-compose build                                                                                                11:56:23
mysql uses an image, skipping
Building vitess
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.7.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 58, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 109, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 213, in build
    force_rm=bool(options.get('--force-rm', False)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 300, in build
    service.build(no_cache, pull, force_rm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 718, in build
    buildargs=build_opts.get('args', None),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 54, in build
    path, exclude=exclude, dockerfile=dockerfile, gzip=gzip
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 103, in tar
    t.add(os.path.join(root, path), arcname=path, recursive=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1938, in add
    self.addfile(tarinfo, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1966, in addfile
    copyfileobj(fileobj, self.fileobj, tarinfo.size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 244, in copyfileobj
    dst.write(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker ps -a                                                                                                        11:56:30
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker ps -q                                                                                                        11:57:25
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker image -q                                                                                                     11:57:28
docker: 'image' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker images -a                                                                                                    11:57:39
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
martin/docker-cleanup-volumes   latest              8c41df286c03        12 weeks ago        22.12 MB
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ df -h                                                                                                               11:57:41
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
run             3.9G  832K  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda4        27G  9.1G   17G  36% /
tmpfs           3.9G   64M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G   32K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1        42G   16G   25G  39% /home
/dev/sda2        42G  9.4G   30G  24% /var
/dev/sda5       1.3G   32M  1.3G   3% /boot
tmpfs           790M   12K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯                                                                                                                     11:57:54
```

docker info

```
[I] ⋊> ~/W/W/cocagne on master ⨯ docker info                                                                                                         12:01:55
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-2359321-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 11.8 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 34.57 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 581.6 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.147 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.131 (2016-07-15)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 4.6.4-1-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.706 GiB
Name: crockford
ID: HO2U:ELWR:LDB3:PMEY:5YOJ:D7YJ:2HJA:PVYG:45K2:J6KI:D6WO:4RUE
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

#### One thing that makes my issue a little different (Where I think the root of the issue comes from)

Before I created a separate partition for `/var`, it was on my root partition, which eventually maxed out.  Once it maxed out, I shrunk my home partition, create a /var partition, copied my root's `/var` to my new `/var`, and removed my old `/var`. But for some reason, docker still think's it's maxed out?  I have no idea.

I also tried to resinstall docker with `sudo pacman -S docker` but nothing.

Edit:  I just tried it with a normal `docker build .` and that works fine.  Somehow `docker-compose` thinks it's out of memory though?

Comment: Check your /tmp to see if you have any space left there.

Comment: /tmp looks fine, du says it has 0 bytes used.

Comment: That's odd, can you confirm with `df | grep /tmp` ? Can you try running `watch -d -i 0.5 df | grep /tmp` when you run docker compose next time to make sure your /tmp doesn't fill up. If you can, also try running an `strace -f` on the docker-compose command to see what file it tries to create and fails to do so. That'll give you a better idea of what might be causing the problem.

Comment: It did not print any differences.  I've determined the device that it's running out of space on is my RAM.  Something must have gotten totally screwed when I messed with my partitions, and unlike before, `docker-compose build` is using up all of my RAM to build a debian 2 image.

Comment: I just did a `watch -d -n 0.5 free -h` and it's pretty clear now that's what is happening.  As soon as I run `docker-compose build`, it drops from about 4gb free to 3, then to ~1.2 then 100mb

Comment: The easy fix would simply be to switch your /tmp from /tmpfs to a disk backed partition, so that docker-compose and the containers don't step on each others' toes. Alternatively cap your containers' resource usage.

Comment: I'm not sure how it that would fix it if we've determined already that docker-compose is not using /tmp at all.

Comment: You do realise your /tmp mount is on tmpfs right? tmpfs is a filesystem backed by RAM. So if your RAM keeps filling up, space in your /tmp also drops. So if all of your RAM gets used, there's no more space left in /tmp (which is backed by tmpfs), to create a temporary files, which is what causes the python stack trace you see with docker-compose.
You can confirm the hypothesis by switching your /tmp to a disk backed partition/file, worst case someone (me) on the internet is wrong :)

Comment: You're right!

I'm pretty sick of messing around with `/etc/fstab`, so I looked into the python documentation and saw this:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir

So I just set $TMPDIR to an empty directory on my home partition and that solved my issue.  I'll go ahead and make an answer, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You've got it right, tiny nitpick, you're looking at Python2 documentation, whereas your `docker-compose` is using Python 3.5.

Comment: Yes absolutely, thanks so much! Do you want to answer the question so I can mark it?

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and write it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The python stack trace from `docker-compose` indicates that it can't seem to create a temporary file. This would indicate there's no space left in `/tmp`.

OP mentioned that his RAM is completely consumed when he runs docker-compose in the comments. Given that and the fact that `/tmp` is mounted on `tmpfs` it makes sense that there is no space left for Python/`docker-compose` to create any temporary files in `/tmp`.

The possible solutions are:

- Temporarily switch the default tempfile generation location by setting one of the following environment variables: `TMPDIR`, `TEMP`, `TMP` (ref: [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir))
- Change `/tmp` to *not* use `tmpfs` and use disk instead.
- Increase the amount of RAM/Swap space on your machine. (You can increase swap without messing with your partitions [like so](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)). `tmpfs` is backed by volatile storage, which means both RAM and Swap should theoretically work.

Note, most of these cases will result in a slowdown of your application, especially if the docker build process is I/O heavy.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

I have a lot of free space in `/home` so I ended up defining `$TMPDIR=$HOME/.tmp`

I didn't realize that `docker-compose build` sends a tarball containing the context of the build to the temporary filesystem.  My MySQL container, which I deleted out of docker-compose, used a very large DB dump.  I figured that this wouldn't matter since I removed MySQL from my `docker-compose.yml` but docker-compose would still include it in the context.

Comment: Not sure what your exact state is, but `docker build` will always send the current directory's contents to the docker daemon, which means if you have the dump in your `$PWD` or in any of it's subdirectories, it all gets passed to daemon via a streaming tarball.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mount -o remount,size=4G,noatime /tmp
```

Comment: Also Try to see if the files where are you building the docker image are so big. You can use the .dockerignore file to exclude files that you consider that are non needed to build the image.